# Find values that appear more than once in the same column or in another column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two columns and would like to find the values where any value in one column is matched by any other row's same column or other column value.

This is my data:

```
my_data <- data.frame(
  storm_name = c("DEAN_2007","FELIX_2007","GUSTAV_2008","IKE_2008","PALOMA_2008","EARL_2010","IGOR_2010","KATIA_2011","JOAQUIN_2015","MATTHEW_2016","HARVEY_2017","IRMA_2017","MARIA_2017","FLORENCE_2018","MICHAEL_2018","DORIAN_2019","LORENZO_2019"),
  year_month_min = c("2007-08","2007-08","2008-08","2008-09","2008-11","2010-08","2010-09","2011-08","2015-09","2016-09","2017-08","2017-08","2017-09","2018-08","2018-10","2019-08","2019-09"),
  year_month_max = c("2007-08","2007-09","2008-09","2008-09","2008-11","2010-09","2010-09","2011-09","2015-10","2016-10","2017-09","2017-09","2017-10","2018-09","2018-10","2019-09","2019-10"))
```

In the context of my data, this means I want to find the year_month_min and year_month_max values where more than one storm took place. In other words, find the year_month values where one or more of the below conditions is met:

- a storm's year_month_min value is matched by another storm's year_month_min value
- a storm's year_month_max value is matched by another storm's year_month_max value
- a storm's year_month_min value is matched by another storm's year_month_max value

The first two of these could easily be achieved with something like

```
my_data %>% dplyr::add_count(year_month_min) %>% dplyr::filter(n>1)
```

and

```
my_data %>% dplyr::add_count(year_month_max) %>% dplyr::filter(n>1)
```

However, I struggle with the third one as I don't know a way to compare values between columns like this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:**
To phrase my problem a bit more simply, I want to find the year-months when more than one storm happened. Hence the need to match between rows columns, but not within rows.

Here is my expected output. Note that the "storm_name" column in the expected output is only a nice to have, what I really need is the "year_month" column. Note how PALOMA_2008 and MICHAEL_2018 are not matched here despite each having the same start and ending year_month because they do not match with any other row.
[image]

Comment: What would the expected output look like?

Comment: The yellow part does not meet the 3rd goal because HARVEY 's year_month_`min` is matched by IRMA's year_month_`min`, not matched by IRMA's year_month_`max`.

Comment: @DarrenTsai Sorry, my explanation was not as clear as it could have been. A matched year-month can satisfy any of the three conditions I above.

Answer (score 0):

**Update after clarification:**

We could do it this way:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

my_data %>% 
  pivot_longer(-storm_name) %>% 
  filter(n()>1) %>% 
  group_by(value) %>% 
  distinct(storm_name) %>% 
  filter(n()>1) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  group_by(value) %>% 
  summarise(storm_name = toString(storm_name))
```

output:

```
 value   storm_name                        
  <chr>   <chr>                             
1 2007-08 DEAN_2007, FELIX_2007             
2 2008-09 GUSTAV_2008, IKE_2008             
3 2010-09 EARL_2010, IGOR_2010              
4 2017-08 HARVEY_2017, IRMA_2017            
5 2017-09 HARVEY_2017, IRMA_2017, MARIA_2017
6 2019-09 DORIAN_2019, LORENZO_2019
```

**First answer:**
Something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

my_data %>% 
  pivot_longer(-storm_name) %>% 
  group_by(name, value) %>% 
  add_count() %>% 
  filter(n()>1)
```

```
   storm_name  name           value       n
   <chr>       <chr>          <chr>   <int>
 1 DEAN_2007   year_month_min 2007-08     2
 2 FELIX_2007  year_month_min 2007-08     2
 3 GUSTAV_2008 year_month_max 2008-09     2
 4 IKE_2008    year_month_max 2008-09     2
 5 EARL_2010   year_month_max 2010-09     2
 6 IGOR_2010   year_month_max 2010-09     2
 7 HARVEY_2017 year_month_min 2017-08     2
 8 HARVEY_2017 year_month_max 2017-09     2
 9 IRMA_2017   year_month_min 2017-08     2
10 IRMA_2017   year_month_max 2017-09     2
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but this only does 1 and 2 of the three points I mentioned. It only matches within the same variables. The year_month_max of DORIAN_2019 is the same as the year_month_min of LORENZO_2019, but this code doesn't find that.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)

my_data %>%  
  pivot_longer(-storm_name) %>%  
  add_count(value, name = "count") %>%  
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = c(value, count)) 

# A tibble: 17 × 5
   storm_name    value_year_month_min value_year_month_max count_year_month_min count_year_month_max
   <chr>         <chr>                <chr>                               <int>                <int>
 1 DEAN_2007     2007-08              2007-08                                 3                    3
 2 FELIX_2007    2007-08              2007-09                                 3                    1
 3 GUSTAV_2008   2008-08              2008-09                                 1                    3
 4 IKE_2008      2008-09              2008-09                                 3                    3
 5 PALOMA_2008   2008-11              2008-11                                 2                    2
 6 EARL_2010     2010-08              2010-09                                 1                    3
 7 IGOR_2010     2010-09              2010-09                                 3                    3
 8 KATIA_2011    2011-08              2011-09                                 1                    1
 9 JOAQUIN_2015  2015-09              2015-10                                 1                    1
10 MATTHEW_2016  2016-09              2016-10                                 1                    1
11 HARVEY_2017   2017-08              2017-09                                 2                    3
12 IRMA_2017     2017-08              2017-09                                 2                    3
13 MARIA_2017    2017-09              2017-10                                 3                    1
14 FLORENCE_2018 2018-08              2018-09                                 1                    1
15 MICHAEL_2018  2018-10              2018-10                                 2                    2
16 DORIAN_2019   2019-08              2019-09                                 1                    2
17 LORENZO_2019  2019-09              2019-10                                 2                    1
```

Comment: This is almost correct! Unfortunately, this also counts cases where a date occurs twice only in the same row. What I am looking for is the year-months when more than one storm happened. Paloma_2008 is a false positive here.

Answer (score 0):

You can separate `year_month_min` and `year_month_max` into different dataframes and match them with `inner_join()`. The suffix also implies which `year_month` of a storm is matched.

```r
library(dplyr)

inner_join(
  select(my_data, year_month = year_month_min, storm_name),
  select(my_data, year_month = year_month_max, storm_name),
  by = "year_month", suffix = c(".min", ".max")
) %>%
  filter(storm_name.min != storm_name.max) %>%
  add_count(year_month)

#   year_month storm_name.min storm_name.max n
# 1    2007-08     FELIX_2007      DEAN_2007 1
# 2    2008-09       IKE_2008    GUSTAV_2008 1
# 3    2010-09      IGOR_2010      EARL_2010 1
# 4    2017-09     MARIA_2017    HARVEY_2017 2
# 5    2017-09     MARIA_2017      IRMA_2017 2
# 6    2019-09   LORENZO_2019    DORIAN_2019 1
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very close to perfect. The only thing it doesn't capture yet is matches within the same column. In my expected output HARVEY and IRMA (yellow) are matched, but with your code they are not.

Comment: @degeso The third goal said *"a storm's year_month_`min` value is matched by another storm's year_month_`max` value"*. The yellow part does ***not*** meet that rule because HARVEY 's year_month_`min` is matched by IRMA's year_month_`min`, not matched by IRMA's year_month_`max`.